# Wordpress, editing links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to change the destination of oNe read more links in wordpress:

[image]

I found this code in the frontpage.php:

```
<?php
     foreach ($query as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);

      printf('<div>');
      printf('<div class="box">');
      printf('<h4>%s</h4>', $post->post_title);

      printf('<img src="%s" />', wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'full')[0]);

      printf('<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt($post->ID));
      printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
      printf('</div>');
      printf('</div>');
     }

     wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

I think I can fiddle around and edit the links so they go to a page of my design through this PHP, however I want to know how to do it through the Wordpress Admin interface.

Because supposedly wordpress should make this easy for you, but I can't seem to find anything on these read more links save the code I found in the PHP.

Do you know the "Wordpress way" to change the link destinations?

Comment: This question might already be answered at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: all you can eat about wordpress "read more": http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text... and more :)

Comment: Thanks but the answer isn't there, I have already looked. I'm trying not to mess with code unless there trully is no "wordpress" way which is supposed to do this basically automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comment to the link provided the reply is simple: The "WordPress" way is the code and the provided [URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text) has everything you need to know about it. There's no Admin way to do this, at least in a native way.

However, in the provided code you have a line that is showing that Read More, which is:

```
  printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
```

basically what this line does is to point to that respective post: it calls the post_permalink function and then the $post->ID tells the function which post to open.

In theory, you can change your link by changing that line to simple HTML:

```
  printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', 'http://www.yoururl.com');
```

This should solve your problem.

**Correct way to do it:**

Add a custom field to the post, insert the url and load it in the loop.

**EDIT:** to address the OP question better

Since this is a loop, represented in your code by the **foreach**, the code is executed once and on every loop the $post->ID changes automatically. By changing the loop by a fixed URL, your 3 posts will link to the same place.

There are several ways to change the behavior, the easiest, cleanest more efficient is to add a custom field to the post. This will create a field in your Post admin area, you insert your URL and access it in the frontend. This way all your posts can link where you want.

Ex:

1. Take a look at [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/faq/) plugin;
2. Create a [text field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/text/) named URL;
3. Use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to access it in the front-end;

Your line of code would like something like this:

```
printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'URL');
```

Comment: Thank you, I had already worked this out theoretically I just haven't implemented it as I wanted to be sure. However I have one extra problem: Will sibmitting the URL in the code change all three read more buttons to be directed to that page? becuase I have 3 buttons each of which I want to direct to a page of my choice so how do I do this?

I hesitate to change the whole body of this code as I know this is a built in function, so I how I change the destination of each read more button?

Comment: Or how do I change the Post Id's of each of the 3 pages?

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for taking the time to explain some of the underlying workings.

Comment: Yes, with the change I proposed initially your 3 buttons would link to the same place, however I've edited the original post with a way for you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The 'read more' links point towards the url for that particular post; changing the destination doesn't make much sense given the context. It sounds like your issue isn't so much about changing the destination of the link *per se*, rather you need to change the design of the page that it actually links to. If that's the case you should look at either [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) if the destination is a page, or [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates) if it's a type of post.

Looking at some of your other questions I gather that you're new to WordPress. Here's a brief summary of how your example is working so that you can hopefully form a better understanding:

- WordPress primarily uses *posts:* these are specific entries for your site. Depending on the nature of the site, they can be blog posts, reviews, news articles, anything really. Just remember that each post is it's own particular *thing* inside WordPress
- The way a post *looks* is determined by the *template* that is used.
- The bit of code that you posted is a *loop*; that one in particular is taking the content of  the variable `$query` (which in your example contains three posts) and then *for each* post runs all the functions in between the `{}` brackets. This is why you end up with three posts/images/links; the function runs three times, once for every post it finds inside of `$query`
- Inside the `{}` brackets, `$post` refers to that particular post. `$post->ID` returns the unique ID number for that post.
- The `get_the_excerpt()` function fetches the excerpt (a short bit of content) for that particular post. You pass it `$post->ID`, so that it fetches the excerpt for the correct post.
- The `post_permalink()` function is what figures out what the url to that particular post. Again, in your example you're passing it `$post->ID`

You should read up on [The Loop](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/the-wordpress-loop-explained-for-beginners); it forms the basis of how WordPress works. If you can get your head around that you're halfway there.

Comment: No right now for the three read more links, there is only one code:

<?php
     foreach ($query as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);

      printf('<div>');
      printf('<div class="box">');
      printf('<h4>%s</h4>', $post->post_title);

      printf('<img src="%s" />', wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'full')[0]);

      printf('<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt($post->ID));
      printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
      printf('</div>');
      printf('</div>');
     }

     wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment: looking at your screenshot I can see there are three posts (Detailing Services, Specials and Service Area). Each post has a read more link, which will point to the full page for that particular post. Those links are generated by the `post_permalink()` function. You have three of them because it's used inside the `foreach()` loop, which runs three times.

Comment: I gather that you're very new to WordPress, so I've expanded my answer above to try and give you more context.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely do some reading on the Loop, I am truly trying to understand this apart from just solving this problem.